# typedef function pointer in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, typedef

I am just experimenting with the `typedef` for functions. I am not clear why removing the parenthesis around `DISPLAY` in my `main()` function causes this code to crash:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*DISPLAY) (int*);

void display(int* data) {
        printf("%d\n", *data);
}

void displayThis(int *val, DISPLAY func_display) {
        func_display (val);
}

int main() {
        int x = 3;
        /*DISPLAY disp = &display;
        disp(&x);*/
        displayThis(&x, DISPLAY display);
        return 0;
}
```

If I compile this and run, it errors out:

```
bash-3.2$ gcc -g display.c
display.c:18:18: error: unexpected type name 'DISPLAY': expected expression
        displayThis(&x, DISPLAY display);
                        ^
1 error generated.
bash-3.2$
```

Here is the version with parenthesis around `DISPLAY` which works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*DISPLAY) (int*);

void display(int* data) {
        printf("%d\n", *data);
}

void displayThis(int *val, DISPLAY func_display) {
        func_display (val);
}

int main() {
        int x = 3;
        /*DISPLAY disp = &display;
        disp(&x);*/
        displayThis(&x, (DISPLAY) display);
        return 0;
}
```

Produces the output as expected:

```
bash-3.2$ gcc -g display.c
bash-3.2$ ./a.out
3
```

Why does parenthesis around `DISPLAY` matter? Can someone help me better understand what is happening?

Thanks.
Andy

Comment: With the parentheses, it's a type cast, which is a type of expression.  Without them, it's syntactically a declaration, which can't appear in an argument list in a function call.

Comment: simpler still is to delete the DISPLAY:  `displayThis(&x, display);` which works because the function type matches, so no cast is needed.  IMO its also better to not cast, since if the function type doesn't match, you'll get a compile error rather than undefined behavior at runtime.

Comment: @TomKarzes Please make your comment an answer so that user3512999 can mark it. The note by Chris should be considered as well.